# Node js runtime profiling measurement

Tags: node.js

I am new to `node.js` but I surprised by searching and finding no way to measure run time profile of a function in `node.js` via code (not looking for an external tool). I am looking for something like this

```
// store time
run_function1();
// store time
// calculate time difference
console.log('function1 ran in '+time_diff+' seconds');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a function in Node.js that is called **hrtime** to get high resolution timings.

[Node Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time)

```
const NS_PER_SEC = 1e9;
const time = process.hrtime();
// [ 1800216, 25 ]

setTimeout(() => {
  const diff = process.hrtime(time);
  // [ 1, 552 ]

  console.log(`Benchmark took ${diff[0] * NS_PER_SEC + diff[1]} nanoseconds`);
  // benchmark took 1000000552 nanoseconds
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)

As example says:

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

Comment: Is it designed to work on node.js too? I receive this message `ReferenceError: performance is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [node.js built in profiler](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/).